# Managing globally errors with $resource and $http in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been looking for a way of managing the http errors that I can have in my angular application. I have been capturing them separately, but I would like to manage them globally. I am using $resource and $http for my http calls. Are there any way of managing them globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [$http interceptor](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http):

Quoted from the docs:

```
angular.module('app',[]).config(function($httpProvider){

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
      return {
       'request': function(config) {
           return config;
        },

       'response': function(response) {
           // do something on success
           return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
         // do something on error

           return $q.reject(rejection);
         }
      };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture global errors:

```
angular.module('app').factory('Interceptor',function($q) {

    'use strict';


    function success(response) {

      return response;
    }

    function error(response) {

      if (response.status === 401) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // here you can broadcast or do anything you want 
        return deferred.promise;
      }
      // otherwise
      return $q.reject(response);
    }

    return function (promise) {

       return promise.then(success, error);
    };
});



angular.module('app').config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('Interceptor');
});
```